# runas with GUI popup?

Tags: windows, uac, windows-server-2012-r2

In Windows Server 2012R2, I've added a context menu item in Explorer to allow me to open certain files with a specific program as Administrator.  I use this command:

`"%SystemRoot%\system32\runas.exe" /user:Administrator "c:\path\program.exe \"%1\""`

It works just fine but the request for the password comes up in a console window and then the program launches after that.  It's superficial but is there a way to cause the UAC password request to appear graphically (as you might see when trying to launch any other program as Administrator) rather than opening a console window?  I know there are some third party tools out there to help with UAC, but I'm wondering if there are any built-in functions to do this.

Comment: I know there are some 3rd party tools floating around the internet that do it, but I don't think there is anything in windows.

Answer (score 4):

Hold the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key,  right-click the application, and choose *Run as different user*.

Comment: Your post doesn't appear to answer the question. Please use the comment section if you need to provide further input or ask OP questions.

Comment: I can't post comments as I don't have 50 rep. Until Superuser changes this I am stuck putting answers and commenting on my own answers.

Comment: You need to gain the rep and comment. Posting a comment as an answer will only mislead OP and get your "*answer*" downvoted and closed. Please read [*Why does this limit exist?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/227680) for more info.

Comment: You can still post answers and ask questions all you like (which may be upvoted and gain you reputation). Please read [*What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?*](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and visit our [help center](http://superuser.com/help) for more information.

Comment: I would also highly recommend you have a look at [*What kind of behavior is expected of users?*](http://superuser.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Already did, and I followed them to the T.

Comment: As stated by comments, this does not answer the question.  The question is not about how to run an arbitrary program via the UI as a different user, it is how to get a traditional UAC popup via a command line--if that is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ShellRunAs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/shellrunas.aspx) from the Sysinternals Toolbox. You can even register a shell extension for your Windows Explorer.

If you want to run a specific program as a different user every time, create a shortcut and edit the Target in the properties of the shortcut.

[image: edit target in shortcut properties]